# Subgroup of a group of bijections

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be the group of bijections of the set $X$, which is assumed to have more than two elements. Let $x_0$ ∈ $X$ and 
$H$ = { $f$ ∈ $G$:  $f$( $x_0$)= $x_0$}. 
Is $H$ normal or not?

Comment: No. Let $x_0,x_1,x_2\in X$. Choose an $f\in G$ such that $f(x_0) = x_0$ and $f(x_2) = x_1$. Now, choose $g\in G$ with $g(x_0) = x_1$, $g(x_1) = x_2$, $g(x_2) = x_0$ and $g(x) = x$ for all other $x\in X$ (if they exist). Then $(gfg^{-1})(x_0) = x_2$, so $gfg^{-1}\notin H$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a stronger statement. Note that if $|X|=n$, then the set of bijections from X to X form a group, which will be isomorphic to the symmetric group of order $n$. Further, the symmetric group contains only one normal subgroup called the alternating subgroup, which has exactly half the size ( and hence is normal). The characterization of the subgroup you have given would mean that it has $(n-1)!$ order, which isn't half of $n!$, the total order. Further, this alternating subgroup exists only when $n  \geq 5$, so if $|X|<=4$, then anyway you will be wrong, since the group then won't have any normal subgroup (called simple), except if $|X| = 4$, but here the normal subgroup is of order $4$, while we would like one of order $6$.

If $|X|$ is infinite, then the finitary symmetric group properties will assert the same, i.e. only the alternating group is a normal group, and it won't be equal  to the set you have specified above.

Comment: "the symmetric group contains only one normal subgroup..." isn't true. $V$(four group)$\triangleleft S_4$ .

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, but that doesn't make a huge difference to the answer, because the index of his subgroup is $n$, not $2$.